# Circular movement

Tags: math, game-physics, equation

I am developing a little videogame using JAVA in which I have to do a circular movement to create a smooth transition of an object but I can't figure it out how to apply the circumference equation to make this.

Here is an image of what I am trying to do:

[image]

The character of the top has to move to the bottom with this circular movement. I know the center of the circumference and the radius but I dont know how to extract an equaction to move this character that also takes into account a given speed.

Any tips please? Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arclength (distance around a circle) is given by `s = rϑ`. Since you want to do this based on a speed, you can take the derivative (basically, divide by t on both sides): `v = rϑ/t`, or `ϑ = vt/r`. Internally, you'll store the values of `r`,`v`, and `t` and use the concept of the unit circle to get the actual `x` and `y` values:

```
x = r * cos(ϑ) = r * cos(vt/r)
y = r * sin(ϑ) = r * sin(vt/r)
```

while you increment `t` on every draw cycle. You'll of course have to translate `(x,y)` based on the center of the circle.